# How do I add a pager for the following code?

Tags: 7

On the `page--product.tpl.php` I use `node_load()` to get all the nodes of a content type. I want to shows 15 post titles per page. How do I add a pager to the page?

I am using the following code.

```
$terms = taxonomy_get_children(arg(2));
foreach ($terms as $term) {
  $whole = taxonomy_select_nodes($term->tid, TRUE, 1, array('t.created' => 'DESC'));
  foreach ($whole as $nid) {
    $node_this = node_load($nid);            
    echo '<h1 class="pdtitle"><a href="#">'.$node_this->title.'</a></h1>';
  }
}
```

Comment: That is not code I would put in a template file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute the following code, and you should get a pager.

```
function mymodule_get_children($tid) {
  $query = db_select('taxonomy_term_data', 't');
  $query->join('taxonomy_term_hierarchy', 'h', 'h.tid = t.tid');
  $query->addField('t', 'tid');
  $query->condition('h.parent', $tid);
  $query->addTag('term_access');
  $query->orderBy('t.weight');
  $query->orderBy('t.name');
  $tids = $query->execute()->fetchCol();

  return $tids;
}

function mymodule_select_nodes(array $tids, $pager = TRUE, $limit = FALSE, $order = array('t.sticky' => 'DESC', 't.created' => 'DESC')) {
  if (!variable_get('taxonomy_maintain_index_table', TRUE)) {
    return array();
  }
  $query = db_select('taxonomy_index', 't');
  $query->addTag('node_access');
  $query->condition('tid', $tids);
  if ($pager) {
    $count_query = clone $query;
    $count_query->addExpression('COUNT(t.nid)');

    $query = $query->extend('PagerDefault');
    if ($limit !== FALSE) {
      $query = $query->limit($limit);
    }
    $query->setCountQuery($count_query);
  }
  else {
    if ($limit !== FALSE) {
      $query->range(0, $limit);
    }
  }
  $query->addField('t', 'nid');
  $query->addField('t', 'tid');
  foreach ($order as $field => $direction) {
    $query->orderBy($field, $direction);
    // ORDER BY fields need to be loaded too, assume they are in the form
    // table_alias.name
    list($table_alias, $name) = explode('.', $field);
    $query->addField($table_alias, $name);
  }
  return $query->execute()->fetchCol();
}

$tids = mymodule_get_children(arg(2));

if (!empty($tids)) {
  $nids = mymodule_select_nodes($tids, TRUE, 1, array('t.created' => 'DESC'));

  if (!empty($nids)) {
    $nodes = node_load_multiple($nids);
    foreach ($nodes as $node) {
      echo '<h1 class="pdtitle"><a href="#">'.$node->title.'</a></h1>';
    }
  }

  echo theme('pager');
}
```

In my test site, replacing `arg(2)` with an existing taxonomy term ID, I get the following output.

```
<h1 class="pdtitle"><a href="#">Appellatio Fere Huic Metuo</a></h1><h2 class="element-invisible">Pages</h2><div class="item-list"><ul class="pager"><li class="pager-current first">1</li>
<li class="pager-item"><a title="Go to page 2" href="/dr72/devel/php?page=1">2</a></li>
<li class="pager-item"><a title="Go to page 3" href="/dr72/devel/php?page=2">3</a></li>
<li class="pager-item"><a title="Go to page 4" href="/dr72/devel/php?page=3">4</a></li>
<li class="pager-item"><a title="Go to page 5" href="/dr72/devel/php?page=4">5</a></li>
<li class="pager-item"><a title="Go to page 6" href="/dr72/devel/php?page=5">6</a></li>
<li class="pager-item"><a title="Go to page 7" href="/dr72/devel/php?page=6">7</a></li>
<li class="pager-item"><a title="Go to page 8" href="/dr72/devel/php?page=7">8</a></li>
<li class="pager-item"><a title="Go to page 9" href="/dr72/devel/php?page=8">9</a></li>
<li class="pager-ellipsis">…</li>
<li class="pager-next"><a title="Go to next page" href="/dr72/devel/php?page=1">next ›</a></li>
<li class="pager-last last"><a title="Go to last page" href="/dr72/devel/php?page=302">last »</a></li>
</ul></div>
```

I used my own functions for the following reasons:

- `taxonomy_get_children()` returns an array of term objects while you are interested only in the taxonomy term IDs. My code gets directly the taxonomy term IDs.
- `taxonomy_select_nodes()` accepts a single taxonomy term ID, while you need the nodes using one or more taxonomy terms. My code returns all the nodes using one or more taxonomy terms matching an array of taxonomy terms.

I also created the page--taxonomy.tpl.php file for the currently enabled theme, and the code works, when I visit the taxonomy page for a taxonomy term with child terms.

[image: screenshot]

In my case, the taxonomy term doesn't have nodes using it, but it has child terms used in nodes.

#### Update

The problem is that both the code you want to add in the template file, and the code executed from Drupal are trying to do the same thing, and this causes a conflict between the two. As result, when a taxonomy term has nodes using it, the output is just the one from Drupal.

[image: screenshot]

When there aren't nodes using the taxonomy term, the output is from the custom template file, and from Drupal.

[image: screenshot]

Both the screenshots has been taken using your theme as default theme.

To avoid this, the code needs to be changed to the following one.

```
function mymodule_get_children($tid) {
  $query = db_select('taxonomy_term_data', 't');
  $query->join('taxonomy_term_hierarchy', 'h', 'h.tid = t.tid');
  $query->addField('t', 'tid');
  $query->condition('h.parent', $tid);
  $query->addTag('term_access');
  $query->orderBy('t.weight');
  $query->orderBy('t.name');
  $tids = $query->execute()->fetchCol();

  return $tids;
}

function mymodule_select_nodes(array $tids, $pager = TRUE, $limit = FALSE, $order = array('t.sticky' => 'DESC', 't.created' => 'DESC')) {
  if (!variable_get('taxonomy_maintain_index_table', TRUE)) {
    return array();
  }
  $query = db_select('taxonomy_index', 't');
  $query->addTag('node_access');
  $query->condition('tid', $tids);
  if ($pager) {
    $count_query = clone $query;
    $count_query->addExpression('COUNT(t.nid)');

    $query = $query->extend('PagerDefault');
    $query->element(10);
    if ($limit !== FALSE) {
      $query = $query->limit($limit);
    }
    $query->setCountQuery($count_query);
  }
  else {
    if ($limit !== FALSE) {
      $query->range(0, $limit);
    }
  }
  $query->addField('t', 'nid');
  $query->addField('t', 'tid');
  foreach ($order as $field => $direction) {
    $query->orderBy($field, $direction);
    // ORDER BY fields need to be loaded too, assume they are in the form
    // table_alias.name
    list($table_alias, $name) = explode('.', $field);
    $query->addField($table_alias, $name);
  }
  return $query->execute()->fetchCol();
}

$tids = mymodule_get_children(arg(2));

if (!empty($tids)) {
  $nids = mymodule_select_nodes($tids, TRUE, 1, array('t.created' => 'DESC'));

  if (!empty($nids)) {
    $nodes = node_load_multiple($nids);
    foreach ($nodes as $node) {
      echo '<h1 class="pdtitle"><a href="#">'.$node->title.'</a></h1>';
    }
  }

  echo theme('pager', array('element' => 10));
}
```

The difference is that now the code is setting the "element" property for the pager to 10. It should the conflict between the pagers, but it changes the value for the GET parameter "page" used from Drupal to identify which page of the pager should be shown, which become similar to "page=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1"; when shown in the URL, it is probable the commas are encoded.

As I commented before, this is not the code I would put in a template file. If you want to change the output of a page, you change its page callback, which means implementing code similar to the following one. (The following is just partial code.)

```
function mymodule_menu(&$items) {
  if (isset($items['taxonomy/term/%taxonomy_term'])) {
    $items['taxonomy/term/%taxonomy_term']['page callback'] = 'mymodule_term_page';
  }
}
```

Even better, it would be using the Views module, and using a view for the taxonomy term page. In this way, it would be possible to alter the output without to write code, and without altering any template file.

In both the cases, Drupal would not be adding a pager while another pager is being added to the same page from a module.

As side note, you are putting in template files things that should be in a module, or that can be easily obtained changing settings for already enabled modules.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to do a custom pager, not based on db query something like [this](http://treehouseagency.com/blog/fmitchell/2010/10/12/drupal-pagination-custom-query), but it is D6 code.
For D7, check [Extenders](http://drupal.org/node/508796) and what the [Database Abstraction Layer](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/group/database/7) page describes is

> Most Drupal database SELECT queries are performed by a call to
>   db_query() or db_query_range(). Module authors should also consider
>   using the PagerDefault Extender for queries that return results that
>   need to be presented on multiple pages

You may also need to check [theme_pager](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!pager.inc/function/theme_pager/7) which displays the pager result.
When calling `theme('pager')` outside a pager query, it's necessary to initialize the pager first with a call to [pager_default_initialize](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!pager.inc/function/pager_default_initialize/7).

Comment: I have deleted the comments, which are not for extended discussion. Please add the information that is useful to answer the question in the question.

Comment: [taxonomy_select_nodes()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21taxonomy%21taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_select_nodes/7) is using the `PagerDefault` extender, and `db_select()`. That is surely not the issue.

Comment: @kiamlaluno, before I posted this answer, OP mentioned only the inner most loop `foreach ($whole as $nid)`. I added a comment that `taxonomy_select_nodes()` uses the `PagerDefault', but it was got deleted.

Comment: It's not your fault. This is what I would call a "moving target" question: a question that is changed basing on the feedback given from the other users. I added my comment to avoid future readers think that using `taxonomy_select_nodes()` doesn't work with `theme('pager')` because it is not using `PagerDefault`.